# MySQL 5.5 on Sparc Solaris 11.3 / there is no mysqladmin

Tags: mysql, mysqladmin

I've installed MySQL on solaris 11.3 sparc:

Interesting thig, there is no:
/usr/local  directory

but:
/usr/mysql/5.5/bin

serverse is running:

```
root@rs1sparc1:/usr/mysql/5.5/bin# svcs -a | grep mysql
**online**         12:03:20 svc:/application/database/mysql:version_55
```

So i tried:

```
# find / -name 'mysqladmin'
```

gives nothing, cant find it, how to manage MySQL?

Comment: Did you look at my answer ?

Comment: Yes, thank you! We need a client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the client. I think previously it was part of the core package which may be the reason for the confusion?. Anyway, just do

```
$ pkg install database/mysql-55/client
```

or

```
$ pkg install database/mysql-56/client
```

depending on your needs.

After this `mysqladmin` command should be available to you with no further configuration as long as `/usr/bin` in your path.

Btw:  For these types of questions http://pkg.oracle.com is your friend. I was able to answer your question with a [search](http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/en/advanced_search.shtml?token=mysqladmin&show=p&rpp=50&v=&action=Advanced%20Search).